# Angular unit test fails because of component in constructor.

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, components, karma-runner

I have a constructor that uses this:

```
  constructor(
    public core: CoreComponent,
  ) {
   //
  }
```

But when i try to test these components with a testcase like this:

```
describe('CoreSubMenuComponent', () => {
  let component: CoreSubMenuComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CoreSubMenuComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TestingModule.forRoot(),
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CoreSubMenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I get a null injector error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[CoreSubMenuComponent -> CoreComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CoreSubMenuComponent -> CoreComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CoreComponent!
```

It is imported into the testingModule so that isn't the issue. I also tried adding it to the providers array. but that just moves it to the angular renderer which can't be added to the providers array. I also added an `@injectable()` tag before the `@component` tag in the `CoreComponent` but it doesn't change my tests failing.

I tried getting it with `@host()` but it throws an error. I also tried to get it with the `Injector` but that also throws an error. These are 4 components that use the `CoreComponent` as a var to get some info from them but they make the tests fail. All my other tests are pass just fine with over 80 tests. Just these 4 won't work because they try to get properties that are defined in the `CoreComponent`.

Does someone know how i could reference this component with an instance so that my tests will pass?

Comment: This may seem like a dumb question but is CoreComponent an actual component or a service?

Comment: Yess it's a component, it's actually the basecode of an ngprime template so you can look at it here: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-blueprint/blob/master/src/app/app.menu.component.ts

Comment: I just called it all core instead of app because I handle other stuff in the app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this error use @host en @optional decorators. this tells the compiler to look for it but not require if it isn't provided:

```
  constructor(
    @Host() @Optional() public core: CoreComponent,
  ) {
    //
  }
```